# PersonalityQuiz guided app in swift fundamentals

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, segue

I've got problem with some additional challenges. I need to filter an array of type Question by some property and then pass it into next View Controller via segue. I've done this:

```
  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    guard let sender = sender as? UIButton else {return}
    if sender == quiz3Button {
        let vc = segue.destination as? QuestionViewController
        vc?.correctQuestions = questions.filter { question in
        return question.quiz == .animals
        }
    } else if sender == quiz4Button {
        let vc = segue.destination as? QuestionViewController
        vc?.correctQuestions = questions.filter { question in
        return question.quiz == .cars
        }
    }
}

@IBAction func quiz3ButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "animals", sender: sender)
}

@IBAction func quiz4Button(_ sender: UIButton) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "cars", sender: sender)
}
```

Filtration works but it doesn't pass value to next View Controller. I declared variable in QuestionViewControler like that

```
var correctQuestions: [Question] = []
```

But when I need to access it I get error "Index out of range". So I figured that its empty..

Segues been made from buttons to VC

Comment: Set a breakpoint at the beginning of your `prepare(for:sender:)` function, and step through it. There are various things that could go wrong to prevent the values from being passed to the destination. We can't tell what's going on without running your app.

Comment: Yeah, no. I can't download that from my work machine, and I'm suggesting something for **you** to do to debug **your** app.

Comment: Ok I've tried something. I had a Navigation Controller between 2 VCs. I deleted that and it worked just fine. But I need that Navigation Controller in between. So any thoughts on how to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I've got it. The NavigationController was the problem here. Added into function push through NC and it worked ;) so closed I think

```
   override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    guard let sender = sender as? UIButton else {return}
    if sender == quiz3Button {
        let destinationViewController = segue.destination as? UINavigationController
        let questionViewController = destinationViewController?.viewControllers.first as! QuestionViewController
        questionViewController.correctQuestions = questions.filter { questions in
        return questions.quiz == .animals
        }
    } else if sender == quiz4Button {
        let destinationViewController = segue.destination as? UINavigationController
        let questionViewController = destinationViewController?.viewControllers.first as! QuestionViewController
        questionViewController.correctQuestions = questions.filter { questions in
        return questions.quiz == .cars
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your button segue invokes a view controller that is inside a navigation controller? You did not provide enough information for your readers to know that.

Comment: When you ask for help with a problem it pays to provide a lot of context.